# Does Hasura support returning array of arrays in a custom action?

Tags: hasura

I am trying to return an array of arrays with a Hasura custom action like this:

```
type Query {
  getFeaturedSubcategories (
    args: GetFeaturedSubcategoriesInput!
  ): [[GetFeaturedSubcategoriesOutput]]
}
```

where:

```
input GetFeaturedSubcategoriesInput {
  featured : Int
}

type GetFeaturedSubcategoriesOutput {
  id : uuid!
  title : String
  thumbnail : String
}
```

But I get this error when using this action:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$[0]",
        "code": "parse-failed"
      },
      "message": "parsing HashMap ~Text failed, expected Object, but encountered Array"
    }
  ]
```

Does this mean that we can't return an array of arrays with Hasura? I can't find any information about this error or if this can be done in Hasura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a limitation from GraphQL.

GraphQL doesn't support tuples, but you can write something like this:

```
type Chart {
  name: String
  series: [Series]
}

type Series {
  name: String!
  data: [DataPoint]
}

type DataPoint {
  x: Int
  y: Float
}
```